# MVVM viewmodel async data initialization

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, windows-store-apps

I am trying to get familiar with Windows Store apps and the MVVM pattern (I'm new to this platform). I have a very simple app that parses a list of Person objects from a json file, then shows them in a gridView. I have created a PeopleViewModel class to serve as the view model for my mainpage, which handles the parsing, and exposes the array of objects for the view. The parsing method:

```
public async Task init()
{
    StorageFolder resourceFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
    resourceFolder = await resourceFolder.GetFolderAsync("Resources");

    StorageFile resourceFile = await resourceFolder.GetFileAsync("persons.json");
    string fileContent = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(resourceFile);

    ObservableCollection<Person> persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

    JsonValue json = JsonValue.Parse(fileContent);
    int personCount = json.GetArray().Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < personCount; i++)
    {
        IJsonValue element = json.GetArray()[i];
        Person p = new Person(element);
        persons.Add(p);
    }

    _persons = persons;
}
```

Then in my XAML, I set this class as the data context of the page:

```
<!-- viewModel namespace defined above -->
<Page.DataContext>
    <viewModel:PeopleViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>
```

Since reading a file is an async operation, I can't put it in the default constructor of PeopleViewModel, I have to call its init() method from the code-behind file of my xaml:

```
private async void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
{
    PeopleViewModel viewModel = this.DataContext as PeopleViewModel;
    await viewModel.init();
}
```

My code is working well, but I'm wondering if this is the right way to do it. Is there a way to initialize my viewmodel with an async method, and keep my code-behind file "clean" (or is this solution considered clean)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure there is, just call an `async void` method from the constructor (no `await` needed), which can in turn now call methods with `await`. (And yes, the best practice is to keep the codebehind clean.)

EDIT:

So based on your experience I left out the part saying that you shouldn't really do this. Instead set up something where an event notifies your viewmodel to load things. Basically you should only use `async void` with event handlers. More on this at the bottom of this page: http://caraulean.com/blog/2013/07/15/using-caliburn-micro-with-async-await/ (Although I prefer MVVMlight or PRISM - the latter even gives you the `INavigationAware` interface where you get your `OnNavigatedTo` events in you VM as well.)

Comment: You should never write async void method without precautions and you should never have async calls inside properties/constructors without clear explanation of side effects.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll amend my comment :)